# RubyKoans: Greed dice scoring

Tags: ruby, dice

The Greed game, from Ruby Koans, where you roll up to 5 dice:

> A set of three ones is 1000 points. A set of three numbers (other than ones) is worth 100 times the number.
>
> A one (that is not part of a set of three) is worth 100 points. A five (that is not part of a set of three) is worth 50 points. Everything else is worth 0 points.

I broke my solution into four methods.

```
def score(dice)
  (1..6).reduce(0) { |sum, n| sum + points(dice, n) }
end

def points(dice, num)
  ((dice.count(num) / 3) * triple(num)) + ((dice.count(num) % 3) * bonus(num))
end

def triple(num)
  num == 1 ? 1000 : (num * 100)
end

def bonus(num)
  [1, 5].include?(num) ? 50 + (50 * (num % 5)) : 0
end
```

I suspect there's a way to avoid having to pass the `dice` array into `points()`, but I can't figure it out. Maybe using a `yield` somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your code is very nice, succinct, and ruby-like.

Two minor issues -

Your `bonus` code is a bit over-sophisticated, which makes it not very readable, and quite brittle. Although it won't fit in one line - a `case` solution will be more suitable here:

```
def bonus(num)
  case num
  when 1 then 100;
  when 5 then 50;
  else 0;
  end
end
```

Also, in `score` I personally think that separating the score calculation from its aggregation is more easy on the eyes:

```
(1..6).map { |n| points(dice, n) }.inject(:+)
```

although, I admit, it is more a matter of taste than anything else...

---

As for your suspicion about not having to pass `dice` to `points`, I don't see a straight-forward way of doing that, or a proper motivation *for* doing it.

Perhaps you want to be able to simplify your block into a straight forward method call (using a syntax like `.map(&some_method)`) - for that you can use proc's [`curry`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Proc.html#method-i-curry) method, but it actually results in a very awkward code, which does not seem to be worth it:

```
def score(dice)
  (1..6).map(&lambda(&method(:points)).curry[dice]).inject(:+)
end
```

Perhaps you want to decouple the point calculation methods from the `dice` array altogether. This can be done easily enough by passing `dice.count(n)` instead of `dice`, as that is all the `points` actually cares about, although this solution will break as soon as point calculation will need more information...

```
def score(dice)
  (1..6).reduce(0) { |sum, n| sum + points(n, dice.count(n)) }
end

def points(num, count)
  ((count / 3) * triple(num)) + ((count % 3) * bonus(num))
end
```

Comment: I agree on all counts! When I figured out a way to implement bonus() with modulus in a one-liner, I couldn't help myself. The case statement definitely makes more sense though. Thanks for the review.